# Do I need to shut down my Google Cloud virtual machine manually?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to working with Google Cloud's virtual machines. I've created a lightweight VM that runs some python code to wrangle data in Google BigQuery. There scripts run first thing in the morning every day, via a scheduled chron job.

My question relates to the optimal running of this VM: should I/can I shut it down when it's not in use, or is this done automatically? If I shut it down I assume the chron job will not spin up the instance?

Any beginner advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to automaticaly start an instance, but you can create a [micro instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) (with shared vcpu) and run a script in cron with the gcloud instances start /stop to start or shutdown your Google Cloud Compute instances when you program.

Comment: Ah great, so if the VM is stopped I can add a line to cron to start it up again, then stop once the script is complete?

Comment: with the gcloud instances start command if the account has permissions yes: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start